# Split-screen (multi window) mode on android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, multi-window, split-screen

On physical device you long press the recent apps button and the split-screen mode is activated. Doing the same on android emulator doesn't work. What to do?
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. **Click on the Overview button**
   [image: Click on the Overview button]
2. **Click on the app icon**
   [image: Click on the app icon]
3. **Select the split-screen option**
   [image: Select the split-screen option]
4. **Select another application**
   [image: Select another application]